# Capybara/Poltergeist, expanding Accordion Table expanding intermittent failure

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I have an issue with expanding a table/row. I did some googling and haven't found any information on such a scenario.

Basically I have a table with 5 or so columns. When clicked on will expand the table and reveal more information. Inside this new information is a button im trying to click on.

Here is the HTML for the row for the table iself:

```
<thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="odd" data-row="0" data-source="/user/01" role="row">
   <td class="sort_1">John Doe</td>
   <td>Person</td>
   <td>Yes</td>
   <td>Yes</td>
   <td> Building 2 </td>
  </tr>
<more table rows here repeated>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The table html itself has an id and everything, but I need to click on any one of the columns within the row itself to get it to expand.

I tried this: `page.find('td', :text => 'John Doe').click` and while it did work successfully, after taking a screenshot it didn't seem to show anything expanded...so im not sure an expanding table will work in this instance. HOWEVER upon re-running it , it worked....but it's not consistent.

The screenshots that poltergeist show have the expanded table barely showing (like just a sliver of expansion). So maybe it's not waiting enough time for it to appear? Im not sure.

When the table expands it basically makes a new  `<tr user-data-row="5">` that will appear underneath the row above when expanded.

For reference here is the HTML for the button that I click after expansion:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5" style="">
 <ul class="list-unstyled">
 <ul class="list-inline">
  <li>
   <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="/stuff/site" data-method="post" rel="no-follow" data-confirm="Generic: Confirmation Dialogue">The Button</a>
  </li>
  <li> </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I thought at first that it was tripping up on the confirmation dialogue popup, but Poltergeist is supposed to avoid those by default. And it seems to do that....so Im not sure what could possible be the problem. With it being inconsistent Im thinking possibly it's a timing issue. My `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 15` since the DB is on a VM, but it hasn't been an issue so far....

Edit:
The code that fails seems to be after this:
    page.find('td', :text => 'John Doe').click
    click_link('The Button')

It seems to work about 50% of the time.

Comment: Weirdly it seems to always fail the first time and then work the second time. Im unsure why this is, as nothing changes between those times.

Comment: What exactly is failing - show your test code - and what exactly is Capybara supposed to be waiting for?  How, exactly, is the row being shown? Is it being animated into visibility (slide_down, etc)? Is it being animated by a library where you can turn off the animations in test mode?

Comment: I added in the piece of code that it fails (it's nothing fancy, literally clicking the text itself to make the accordian table open, and then clicking a button). The new row is being animated as a sort of "reveal" ie: clicking anywhere on the original row will cause a new row to animate/open underneath (it takes about a second for the new row to fully show). As far as im aware there is no library that allows me to turn it off for test mode.

Comment: So the `click_button` line is failing with something like 'Cant find button'?? or there is no error and it just doesn't appear to do what you expect?  If the latter and there really is no way to disable animations in test mode (`$.fx.off = true` for anything jquery driven for instance) then it's possible for clicks to hit in the wrong place because the link is moving.  If there really is no way to disable the animations (not usual) all you can do is sleep the amount of time the animation takes before calling `click_link`

Comment: That's the funny thing, it never error's out on the click_link portion, but it appears to never go to the next page (Where the button takes you). All my errors are referencing the next page (Element not found/etc...). 

From screenshots i've taken before/after the button has been clicked it seems like it stays on the same page. So im not sure of the "alert" popup is somehow interfering with it or it's not waiting long enough after clicking the button to get to the next page.

Comment: try `sleep 2` before the click_link and see if it makes a difference - if it does it tells you it's the animation causing the click to miss  - also you should handle the alert popup yourself since poltergeist is the only driver that has a default handling for it - every other driver will error.

Comment: I will try that, however if it's "missing" it....wouldn't it give an error, or maybe poltergeist "thinks" it clicked where the button should be but it isn't actually there yet due to the animation?

Comment: correct -- Poltergeist calculates where to click, and then sends a mouse event -- before that mouse event is processed it's possible for the element to move, so the click happens but not on the link  -- You can do find(:link, 'The Button').trigger(:click)`  which doesn't really send the same mouse events as a user would so it's not technically emulating a user and should only really be used as a last resort - but will hit the button -- best solution is to disable animations in test mode.

Comment: This seems to have worked correctly! I figured it was probably something to do with the animation. I hate using sleeps but it seems necessary for this particular spot. Thanks. Not sure if you want to "answer" this post so I can give credit for your answer.

Comment: I've added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using some Capybara drivers with animations it's possible for clicks to miss their targets.  This happens because the location for the mouse click to occur is calculated, the mouse event is created, and submitted to the "browsers" queue for processing.  Before the event is processed it's possible for the destination element to move enough that the click misses the element.  There are a few ways to handle this

1. The best solution all around (speed, reliability, validity of mouse events) is to disable animation in the test environment.  This can usually be done by conditionally setting a few JS variables depending on the libraries being used.
2. Sleep for a small time before attempting to click so the animation has time to complete - This is slower, but still keeps "real" mouse clicks that travel through the pages event processing like a users would.
3. Use #trigger to simulate a click - `element.trigger(:click)` - this will be quick but can short circuit of lot of things that are done to make sure tests validly replicate what a user can do and can therefore lead to tests that miss failures.  It should be used as the method of last resort